# Phonegap CLI does not create .apk file

Tags: android, cordova, command-line-interface

I've created a sample project using PhoneGap's CLI, but can't run it on Android.
The `apk` file is not generated. I've got Android, Java and ant installed, and all the necessary paths set.

Any ideas what's wrong?
Here is the output from the console:

```
phonegap local run -V android
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
[phonegap] Wrote out Android application name to "PGlol"
[phonegap] Wrote out Android package name to "pl.gda.pg29lol"
[phonegap] Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
[phonegap] Compiling platform "android" with command "F:\phonegap_projects\pg29lol\platforms\android\cordova\build"" (output to follow)...
[phonegap] Cleaning project...
WARNING: [ --debug | --release | --nobuild ] not specified, defaulting to --debug.
Buildfile: F:\phonegap_projects\pg29lol\platforms\android\build.xml
-set-mode-check:
[phonegap] Platform "android" compiled successfully.
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
[phonegap] Wrote out Android application name to "PGlol"
[phonegap] Wrote out Android package name to "pl.gda.pg29lol"
[phonegap] Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
[phonegap] Running app on platform "android" with command" "F:\phonegap_projects\pg29lol\platforms\android\cordova\run" --device" (output to follow)...
[phonegap] Cleaning project...
WARNING: [ --debug | --release | --nobuild ] not specified, defaulting to --debug.
Buildfile: F:\phonegap_projects\pg29lol\platforms\android\build.xml


-set-mode-check:
```

**Failed to find apk, make sure you project is built and there is an apk in \bin.  To build your project use '\cordova\build'**

```
[phonegap] Platform "android" ran successfully.
[phonegap] successfully installed onto device
```

Will be grateful for help.

Comment: Did you ever run `cordova/build`?

Answer (score 1):

Before you can run your android app you need use the command: cordova build

This will build the apk that "phonegap local run -V android" will run

Comment: According to documentation "As an alternative, the combined run command performs both the build and install operations in one line". I tried both ["phoegap run"] and ["phonegap build" followed by "phonegap install"]. Both approaches do not work and have the same result in fact. Shall I use "cordova" command instead of "phonegap" ????

Comment: Yes, you need to use "cordova build". I am not sure why they are requiring both cordova CLI and phonegap CLI to be used, but I have worked with this for a while now and I always have to run the cordova command first

Comment: Thanks for your help. It turned out to be a problem with missing package in my android SDK, which I was able to identify using approach from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140227/how-to-build-apache-cordova-project-from-command-line by "fil maj". Now everything works well, even when I use "phonegap CLI only" approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this steps:**

phonegap run android in terminal 
**strong text**[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...

if you already installed Andorid SDK then automatically emulator run. 
Ok then you check your local disk where you stored your phongegap project -> and goto Platform ->android ->ant-Build: there .apk File generated.